# Why does not the TMC from traffic data match with the TMC from PDE layers LINK_TMC_FC?

Tags: here-api

I tried to match the data I got from traffic API to the link IDs, using the PDE layers LINK_TMC_FC, but the TMCs do not match.

I used tiles to get the TMC layers through the PDE, and converted the corresponding tile to the lat long values (https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/resource-tile.html) and used bounding box to retrieve the traffic data.

Here are the requests I used:

Traffic data:

```
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.2/flow.xml?app_id={YOUR-APP-ID}&app_code={YOUR-APP-CODE}&bbox=42.5391,-71.0156;42.1875,-71.3672&responseattributes=sh,fc
```

PDE TMC layer:

```
https://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json?layer=LINK_TMC_FC1&level=9&tilex=309&tiley=376&app_id={YOUR-APP-ID}&app_code={YOUR-APP-CODE}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is sample code for getting TMC data onto your map. Happy Coding!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Traffic Flow and Jam Factor</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css">

        <script src="https://qa.rd.account.here.com/js/sdk/sso.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-clustering.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-data.js"></script>




<meta name="csrf-token" content="YZqjYY5AoVvEa11f2Oph8T7F/3TV4eXyhmeNGaaVA8pEKyV6GauelevYvqiH64JtoCqWj54WD5DqJ4k6dYllHQ==" />



    </head>
    <body>




<div class="ctrl-panel">
    <span id="toggle-ctrl-panel" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>
    <p>This Example Shows how to find Traffic Flow and Jam Factor for a given latitude and longitude using HERE platform.</p>

    <h5>Coordinates</h5>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type='text' class="form-control input-wide" id='coord_input' value='25.284867,51.505572' />

    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="trafficButton" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Find Traffic"/>

    <div id="noTrafficText" style="color:red"></div>

    <hr class="separator">

    Address: <br/>
            <input style='width:100%;' type="text" name="addressText" id="addressText" readonly>

    <a id="checkOn" href="" style="display:none" target="_blank" >Check on here.com</a>


<div id="mapContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 900px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
    (C) HERE 2016
    */

    var app_id = "{YOUR-APP-ID}";
    var app_code = "{YOUR-APP-CODE}";



        // Check whether the environment should use hi-res maps
        var hidpi = ('devicePixelRatio' in window && devicePixelRatio > 1);

        // check if the site was loaded via secure connection
        var secure = (location.protocol === 'https:') ? true : false;

        // Create a platform object to communicate with the HERE REST APIs
        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            useCIT: true,
            app_id: app_id,
            app_code: app_code,
            useHTTPS: secure
        }),
        maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers(hidpi ? 512 : 256, hidpi ? 320 : null),
        group = new H.map.Group(),
        markerGroup = new H.map.Group(),
        geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();

        // Instantiate a map in the 'map' div, set the base map to normal
        map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'), maptypes.normal.map, {
            center: {lat:25.284867,lng:51.505572},
            zoom: 15,
            pixelRatio: hidpi ? 2 : 1
        });


        // to store the returned locations
        var group;

        // Enable the map event system
        var mapevents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

        // Enable map interaction (pan, zoom, pinch-to-zoom)
        var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapevents);

        // Enable the default UI
        var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, maptypes);

        // add long click in map event listener
        map.addEventListener('longpress', handleLongClickInMap);

        map.addObject(markerGroup);


        // setup the Streetlevel imagery
        //platform.configure(H.map.render.panorama.RenderEngine);

        // if the window is resized, we need to resize the viewport
        window.addEventListener('resize', function() { map.getViewPort().resize(); });


    var pointA;
    var startMarker = null;
    var coordInput = document.getElementById("coord_input");
    var bErrorHappened = false;

    var bLongClickUseForcoordInput = true; // for long click in map we toggle coordInput
    var level, pdeLayer, tileY, tileX;
    var listTMCs= new Object();
    var TMC;
    var linkIDInfo;
    var TMCCode = [];
    var latlngLocation;

    var flowItems = [];
    var tmcCodesToCheck = [];

    var marker,currentBubble;
    var indexPCValue;

    /********************************************************
            coordInput selection via LongClick in map
    ********************************************************/
    function handleLongClickInMap(currentEvent)
    {
        var lastClickedPos = map.screenToGeo(currentEvent.currentPointer.viewportX, currentEvent.currentPointer.viewportY);

        if(bLongClickUseForcoordInput)
        {
            var line1 = "" + lastClickedPos.lat + "," + lastClickedPos.lng;
            coordInput.value = line1;

        }

    }

    /************************************
        Start Traffic
    ************************************/
    var startTrafficCalculation = function()
    {
        clearLastTrafficCalculation();
        latlngLocation = coordInput.value;
        reverseGeocoding(coordInput.value, true);
    }
    trafficButton.onclick = startTrafficCalculation;

    /************************************
            Geocode start/destination
    ************************************/

    function reverseGeocoding(rgLocation){

        var reverseGeocodingParameters = {
            pos: rgLocation + "," + 500,
            mode: 'trackPosition',
            maxResults: 1,
            addressattributes: 'all',
            locationattributes: 'all',
            responseattributes: 'all',
            //minResults: 1,
            //additionaldata: 'SuppressStreetType,Unnamed',
            gen:9
        };

        // Call the geocode method with the geocoding parameters,
        // the callback and an error callback function (called if a communication error occurs):
        geocoder.reverseGeocode(
            reverseGeocodingParameters,
            onSuccess,
            function(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        );
    }

    // Define a callback function to process the response:
    function onSuccess(result) {
        var location = result.Response.View[0].Result[0];
        console.log(location);
        var latitude = location.Location.NavigationPosition[0].Latitude;
        var longitude = location.Location.NavigationPosition[0].Longitude;

        markerGroup.removeAll();
        marker = new H.map.Marker({lat:latitude,lng:longitude});
        // Add the marker to the group (which causes// it to be displayed on the map)
        markerGroup.addObject(marker);
        //Zoom to the marker's bbox
        map.setViewBounds(markerGroup.getBounds());

        //get LinkId from reversegeocoder response
        linkIDInfo = location.Location.MapReference.ReferenceId;
        var fcValue = location.Location.LinkInfo.FunctionalClass;


        // calculate pde tile values
        var level = fcValue + 8;
        var tileSize = 180 / (Math.pow(2,level));
        var tileY = Math.floor((latitude + 90) / tileSize);
        var tileX = Math.floor((longitude + 180) / tileSize);



        // Display returned location with the address label:
        document.getElementById("addressText").value = location.Location.Address.Label;

        // PDE layer to get TMC code
        var pdeLayer = 'LINK_TMC_FC' + location.Location.LinkInfo.FunctionalClass;
        getPDETrafficCorridorSearch(level, pdeLayer, tileY, tileX);
            getflowAvailablity();

    }

    function getPDETrafficCorridorSearch(plevel, ppdeLayer, ptileY, ptileX){


            var url = ['https://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/tile.json?',
                '&app_id=',
                app_id,
                '&app_code=',
                app_code,
                '&layer=',
                ppdeLayer,
                '&level=',
                plevel,
                '&tilex=',
                ptileX,
                '&tiley=',
                ptileY,
                "&callback=processTrafficCorridorSearch"
                ].join('');
                // Send request.
                script = document.createElement("script");
                script.src = url;
                document.body.appendChild(script);


    }

    function getflowAvailablity(){


            var url = ['https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/flowavailability.json?',
                '&app_id=',
                app_id,
                '&app_code=',
                app_code,
                '&mapview=',
                map.getViewBounds().getTop()+","+map.getViewBounds().getLeft()+";"+map.getViewBounds().getBottom()+","+map.getViewBounds().getRight(),
                "&zoom=",
                map.getZoom(),
                "&profile=NTdefault"
                ].join('');
                // Send request.
                script = document.createElement("script");
                script.src = url;
                //document.body.appendChild(script);


    }



    // callback for static layer from PDE
    function processTrafficCorridorSearch(resp){
        if(resp ==null || resp.Rows==null|| resp.Rows== "[]" || resp.Rows=="[]" || resp.Rows== ""){
            console.log("Oops! Something went wrong.");
            document.getElementById("noTrafficText").innerHTML = "Traffic is not available at this link!";
            return;
        }
        // populate
        var rows=resp.Rows;
        for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            listTMCs[rows[i].LINK_ID]=rows[i];
        }
        findTMCFromLinkID();
    }



    function checkLinkID(rows) {
         if (rows.LINK_ID == linkIDInfo){
            return rows;
         }

    }

    function findTMCFromLinkID() {


        var linkTMC =listTMCs[linkIDInfo];


        if (linkTMC === undefined){
            document.getElementById("noTrafficText").innerHTML = "Traffic is not available at this link!";

        }else{

            // one link may have more than 1 TMC associated with it
            var tempTMCCode = linkTMC.TMCS;
            TMCCode = tempTMCCode.split(',');
            // Select a portion of TMC code (e.g 31-2810T = 2810)
            // to match with TMC.PC from Traffic API response
            // and also figure out QD value to match Traffic API response
            for(var x=0;x<TMCCode.length;x++){
                tmcCodesToCheck[x]=new Object();
                if(TMCCode[x].indexOf("-")>-1 ){
                    var pos=TMCCode[x].indexOf("-");
                    tmcCodesToCheck[x].TMC=TMCCode[x].substring(pos+1,TMCCode[x].length-1);
                    tmcCodesToCheck[x].QD = "+";
                }
                if(TMCCode[x].indexOf("N")>-1){
                    var pos=TMCCode[x].indexOf("N");
                    tmcCodesToCheck[x].TMC=TMCCode[x].substring(pos+1,TMCCode[x].length-1);
                    tmcCodesToCheck[x].QD = "+";
                }
                if(TMCCode[x].indexOf("+")>-1){
                    var pos=TMCCode[x].indexOf("+");
                    tmcCodesToCheck[x].TMC=TMCCode[x].substring(pos+1,TMCCode[x].length-1);
                    tmcCodesToCheck[x].QD = "-";
                }
                if( TMCCode[x].indexOf("P")>-1){
                    var pos=TMCCode[x].indexOf("P");
                    tmcCodesToCheck[x].TMC=TMCCode[x].substring(pos+1,TMCCode[x].length-1);
                    tmcCodesToCheck[x].QD = "-";
                }
            }
            // call traffic API for coordinates from reverse geocoding response
            findTrfficData(latlngLocation);


        }
    }

    function findTrfficData(latlngLocation){
            var url = ['https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?',
                'app_id=',
                app_id,
                '&app_code=',
                app_code,
                '&prox=',
                latlngLocation,
                ',200',
                '&responseattributes=sh,fc',
                '&units=metric',
                '&jsoncallback=updateTraffic'
                ].join('');
                // Send request.
                script = document.createElement("script");
                script.src = url;
                document.body.appendChild(script);
                console.log(script.src);
    }


    updateTraffic = function(response)
    {
        if(response.RWS)
        {

            for(i = 0; i < response.RWS.length; i++)
            {
                if(response.RWS[i].RW)
                {
                    for(j = 0; j < response.RWS[i].RW.length; j++)
                    {
                        if(response.RWS[i].RW[j].FIS)
                        {
                            for(k = 0; k < response.RWS[i].RW[j].FIS.length; k++)
                            {
                                    if(response.RWS[i].RW[j].FIS[k])
                                    {
                                    for(l = 0; l < response.RWS[i].RW[j].FIS[k].FI.length; l++)
                                    {
                                        var FI = response.RWS[i].RW[j].FIS[k].FI[l];
                                        for(var x=0;x<tmcCodesToCheck.length;x++){
                                            if(FI.TMC.PC ==  parseInt(tmcCodesToCheck[x].TMC) &&
                                                tmcCodesToCheck[x].QD == FI.TMC.QD){
                                                console.log("match"+tmcCodesToCheck[x].QD+tmcCodesToCheck[x].TMC);
                                                flowItems.push(FI);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            renderFlowTem(flowItems);


        }
    }





    function clearLastTrafficCalculation()
    {
        bErrorHappened = false;
        bLongClickUseForStartPoint = true;

        group.removeAll();

    }

    //--- Helper - Create Start / Destination marker
    var createIconMarker = function (line1) {
        var svgMarker = svgMarkerImage_Line;

        svgMarker = svgMarker.replace(/__line1__/g, line1);

        return new H.map.Icon(svgMarker, {
            anchor: new H.math.Point(24, 57)
        });
    };

    var zindex=1;

    function renderFlowTem(flowItems){
        for(l = 0; l < flowItems.length; l++){
                                        var FI = flowItems[l],
                                            shp,
                                            JF,
                                            CN,
                                            point;

                                        if(FI.SHP && FI.CF)
                                        {

                                            JF = FI.CF[0].JF;
                                            CN = FI.CF[0].CN;

                                            // CN value < 0.7 indicates the flow data might be
                                            // predicted using histroical data , only CN values >7
                                            // signify real time data
                                            if( CN < 0.7)
                                                continue;

                                            for(m = 0; m < FI.SHP.length; m++)
                                            {
                                                var debugpoints = new Array();

                                                var strip = new H.geo.Strip();

                                                for(n = 0; n < FI.SHP[m].value.length; n++)
                                                {
                                                    var cpoints = FI.SHP[m].value[n].trim().split(" ");

                                                    for(z = 0; z < cpoints.length; z++)
                                                    {
                                                        strip.pushLatLngAlt.apply(strip, cpoints[z].split(',').map(function(item) { return parseFloat(item); }));
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                var updatedStrip;
                                                var stripArray=strip.getLatLngAltArray();
                                                console.log(stripArray);
                                                if(FI.TMC.QD == "-"){
                                                    updatedStrip=new H.geo.Strip();
                                                    for(n = stripArray.length; n-3 >= 0; n=n-3)
                                                    {
                                                        updatedStrip.pushLatLngAlt(stripArray[n-3],stripArray[n-2],stripArray[n-1]);
                                                    }
                                                }else{
                                                    updatedStrip=strip;
                                                }
                                                console.log(updatedStrip);

                                                var polyline = new H.map.Polyline(updatedStrip,
                                                {
                                                    style:
                                                    {
                                                        lineWidth: 10,
                                                        strokeColor: getColorForJF(JF),
                                                        //arrows: { fillColor: 'white', frequency: 2, width: 0.8, length: 0.7 }
                                                    }
                                                });

                                                polyline.$JF = JF;
                                                polyline.$CN = CN;
                                                polyline.$TMC = FI.TMC.QD+""+FI.TMC.PC;

                                                polyline.addEventListener("pointerdown", function(e)
                                                {
                                                    if(currentBubble)
                                                        //ui.removeBubble(currentBubble);
                                                    var html =  '<div>'+
                                                        '<p style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px;">JamFactor: ' + e.target.$JF +'</p>'+
                                                        '<p style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px;">Confidence: ' + e.target.$CN +'</p>'+
                                                        '<p style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px;">TMC: ' + e.target.$TMC +'</p>'+
                                                        '</div>';

                                                    var pos = map.screenToGeo(e.currentPointer.viewportX, e.currentPointer.viewportY);

                                                    currentBubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(pos, { content: html });
                                                    ui.addBubble(currentBubble);

                                                    //var style= polyline.getStyle().getCopy({lineWidth : });

                                                    e.target.setZIndex(zindex++);

                                                    //e.target.setStyle(style);

                                                });
                                                markerGroup.addObject(polyline);
                                            }
                                        }
        }
        document.getElementById("checkOn").href="https://share.here.com/l/"+latlngLocation+"?z=18&t=traffic&p=yes";
        document.getElementById("checkOn").style.display="block";
    }
    //You can interpret JF for example: 0 ≤ JF ≤ 4 is light congestion;
    // 4 ≤ JF ≤ 8 is moderate congestion; and JF > 8 is heavy congestion.
    // and JF > 10 is road blocked.
    getColorForJF = function(jamFactor)
    {
        if(jamFactor < 4.0)
            return 'rgb(138,198,144)';
        else if(jamFactor < 6.5)
            return 'rgb(254,212,3)';
        else if(jamFactor < 8.0)
            return 'rgb(254,153,37)';
        else if(jamFactor < 10.0)
            return 'rgb(227,15,56)';
        else if (jamFactor == 10.0 || jamFactor > 10.0)
            return 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    }
</script>
        </div>
        <div id="frame-container"/>
    </body>
</html>
```